# Apache RewriteEngine CSS & RewriteRules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got a couple of issues with using the rewrite engine on my localhost.
I'm working on a site located in my `www/project1/` folder and I am trying to use the rewrite engine. However I run into some issues:

First of all this is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^profile$ ./index.php?p=userprofile 
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ ./index.php?p=userprofile&id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule $(.*)$ ./index.php&c=$1
```

Bascially I want to rewrite 
all `/profile` links to `index.php?p=userprofile`
 
rewrite all `/profile/5` links to `index.php?p=userprofile&id=5`

and all others (such as `/somepage`) to `index.php?c=somepage`

When using the above .htaccess I first of all get a 500 Internal Server Error. However when removing the last rewriterule this error goes away.

With the last rule removed, another problem rises
When going to `localhost/project1/profile` everything works perfectly fine but when adding another parameter: `localhost/project1/profile/5` all my css is gone.

My CSS is included as follows: `href="style/main.css"`

the file is thus located in `localhost/project1/style/main.css`

Now I tried making the path relative by adding a `/`
But then the CSS isn't applied at all, not on `index.php` nor on `project1/profile`

Any solution to this so I can get my 3 rules to work?

Comment: First of all, why do you have a dot at the start of all of your rewritten paths? Those should start with a slash `/index.php...`, not `./index.php...` Also `/index.php&c=$1` should be `/index.php?c=$1`. Are those just typos here or in your actual config? Regarding the RewriteCond, that only applies to the immediately following RewriteRule, it does not apply to subsequent rules, so if you want to do the valid file check for the other two rules you'll need to add the RewriteCond again in front of each of them (could be the issue with your CSS file and other 500 errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last rule is just wrong.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^profile$ index.php?p=userprofile [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ index.php?p=userprofile&id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?c=$1 [L]
```

About the CSS, you have to use an **absolute** path. So you'll need `href="/project1/style/main.css"`

You can also use a .htaccess rule for that instead of changing all urls.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*/style.css$ style.css [NC,L]
```

**You have to put it before all rules in your .htaccess.**